# Prisma Nodejs - sum days in table

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

i have this model

```
model Products {
  id          Int    @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
  name        String @db.VarChar(200)
  quantity    Int
  kg          Int
  arrived     String @db.VarChar(200)
  daysInStock Int
  status      String @db.VarChar(200)
  Suite       Suite? @relation(fields: [suiteId], references: [id])
  suiteId     Int?
}
```

the arrived field will contain the day, the product are registed in stock
and i need that daysInStock will sum every day, so if the data entry today, after 10 days, i need that daysInStock have the value equal 10

there's any way to make it with prisma?